# Reduce the number of trigonometry calls in $ f(x,y,n)=2^{n-1}(1-\cos{\frac{x\pi}{2^n}})(1-\cos{\frac{y\pi}{2^n}})$ (and $\sum_{n=0}^bf(x,y,n))$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Using trigonometric identities rearrange the following function to have a single trigonometry call:

$$
f(x,y,n)=2^{n-1}\left(1-\cos{\frac{x\pi}{2^n}}\right)\left(1-\cos{\frac{y\pi}{2^n}}\right)
$$

I'm looking for help in optimizing it for a computer program I'm working on. Bonus points: run this entire summation with a single trigonometry reference. How can I get the $n$ out of the trigonometry call?
$$
\sum_{n=0}^b{f(x,y,n)}
$$

Comment: Why do you think it is possible?

Comment: Knowing that there are hundreds of trigonometric identities & theorems, combined with the number of brilliant posts I've consumed on this site before -- I figured that the odds were in my favor.

Comment: How large is $n$ ?

Comment: We're talking computer bit analysis here, so b=32 is a typical number. 53 or 64 is a good possibility in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, $x$ and $y$ are unrelated and arbitrary, and you do have to compute the two cosines.

Second bad news, I see no way to avoid the full evaluation of the terms in the summation.

---

To reduce the number of trigonometric calls drastically, you can rely on the recurrence relation

$$\cos(2^{-(n-1)}\alpha)=2\cos^2(2^{-n}\alpha)-1$$ or $$c_{n-1}=2c_n^2-1.$$

Anyway, this is numerically unstable when $c_n\approx1$, and instead,

$$1-c_{n-1}=2(1-c_n)(2-(1-c_n)).$$

---

Finally, note that the terms decrease roughly like $32^{-n}$ so that you don't necessarily need to accumulate all of them, contrary to my initial opinion.